# Email Notification on new MySQL database entry

Tags: php, mysql, email, notifications

I've been creating a blog using tutorials around the web and I have a working comments system but what I would like is if when the user adds a comment that I get an email. I'd really love if you could explain how exactly I could go about implementing a notification. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Current Form:

```
<form id="commentform" method="post" action="process.php">

<p><input type="hidden" name="entry" id="entry" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="timestamp" id="timestamp" value="<?php echo $commenttimestamp; ?>">

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name (required)" /><br />

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" title="Mail (will not be published) (required)" /><br />

<input type="text" name="url" id="url" title="Website" value="http://" /><br />

<br />
<textarea  title="Your Comment Goes Here" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit_comment" id="submit_comment" value="Add Comment" /></p>

</form>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_comment'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comment'])) {
        die("You have forgotten to fill in one of the required fields! Please make sure you submit a name, e-mail address and comment.");
    }

    $entry = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['entry']));
    $timestamp = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['timestamp']));
    $name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $url = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['url']));
    $comment = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));
    $comment = nl2br($comment);

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $name = addslashes($name);
        $url = addslashes($url);
        $comment = addslashes($comment);
    }

    if (!eregi("^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$", $email)) {
         die("The e-mail address you submitted does not appear to be valid. Please go back and correct it.");
    }

    mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') ;
    mysql_select_db ('ultankc');

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO php_blog_comments (entry, timestamp, name, email, url, comment) VALUES ('$entry','$timestamp','$name','$email','$url','$comment')");

    header("Location: post.php?id=" . $entry);
}
else {
    die("Error: you cannot access this page directly.");
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not use addslashes to escape data for database queries.  Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, or better yet, use prepared queries...

Comment: Every once in a while it is lovely to see injection work. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you are looking for code in PHP that can send an email, below is one from [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php) for you to look at. Insert the code to send email just before or after you `INSERT` the comment into your database.

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email'; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

[Requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php):

> For the Mail functions to be
>   available, PHP must have access to the
>   sendmail binary on your system during
>   compile time. If you use another mail
>   program, such as qmail or postfix, be
>   sure to use the appropriate sendmail
>   wrappers that come with them. PHP will
>   first look for sendmail in your PATH,
>   and then in the following:
>   /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc:/usr/ucblib:/usr/lib.
>   It's highly recommended to have
>   sendmail available from your PATH.
>   Also, the user that compiled PHP must
>   have permission to access the sendmail
>   binary.

Comment: What if I want the email to display the information that was entered into the comment form? I want it so that it sends me the name, email and entry of the comment.

Comment: The `$message` variable holds yours message. Use string concatenation to create the desired message and send that.

Comment: Is it possible for me to test this using Mamp. I don't appear to be receiving any emails when I enter the comments.

Comment: You need to have a mail server running on the machine. More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php). Also read the update to the answer.